# Heroku server api call (localhost) not working

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm on the final stretch of my web app, and I'm trying to deploy it with Heroku. The backend is very simple, and just uses express and while I was coding, a simple localhost server to create a token on login (localhost:8080/login). Unfortunately, on Heroku the login and token generation will not work unless I'm using my computer and I've ran node server.js already in my terminal. Also not sure if this context is needed, but locally, my react app is launched at localhost:3000 while the server is localhost:8080/login. I've heard that I should change them both to be the same localhost with some slight changes to the url, but nothing's worked so far. What changes do I need to make to the relevant code below so that Heroku will use its own server for the api call?

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
      token: 'test123' // simple test send token
    });
  });

  app.listen(8080, () => console.log('API is running on http://localhost:8080/login'));
```

Server.js (I have to run npm start, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then node server.js in order to login properly)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Login.css';

async function loginUser(credentials) {
 return fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
 })
   .then(data => data.json())
}

export default function Login({ setToken }) {
  const [username, setUserName] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const token = await loginUser({
      username,
      password
    });
    setToken(token);
  }

  return(
    <div className="login-wrapper">
      <h1>Please Log In</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <p>Username</p>
          <input type="text" onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          <p>Password</p>
          <input type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
        </label>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

Login.propTypes = {
  setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Login component where token will be generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your Heroku app's localhost is not pointing to your server application.

The most straight forward way to resolve this is to publish your server application on Heroku as well, then change your function `loginUser` to point to the URL to your server application's Heroku URL. You may later refactor the URL to refer to an environment variable so you have zero code change when developing locally and pushing to Heroku. This [deploy guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) will probably come in handy for you in this case.

If you do not intend to have publish your server application on Heroku due to any reason, you may also start your server on a local machine and expose it through [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started-expose), but you will need to refactor the fetch URL now as ngrok will have different URL every time you start it.